# How do I set ISTIO VirtualService host using configMap value WITHOUT helm

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, istio, argocd, gitops

I am in need of being able to set a host string in an istio virtualService using a value located in a configMap.  I cannot use HELM lookup because I am using ArgoCD to deploy which does not support helm lookup.

What I want to do:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: elastic-vs
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "1"
spec:
  gateways:
    - istio-system/ex-ingress
  hosts:
    valueFrom: # Can I do this somehow?
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: my-config-map
        key: my-host-var 
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: elasticsearch.monitoring.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 9200
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hello! Have you found an answer on this?